# How to identify execution plan will consider nested loop join or hash join algorithm?

Tags: sql-server, join

I am wondering is there any specific data pattern/algorithm which is used to decide whether to go nested loop join or hash match join. If both the inputs are sorted on the join column with equivalent number of records it might select Merge Join, but anyone can explain about other two?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, nested loops is chosen when both sides of the join are relatively small (speaking to the cardinality) or when one side is small and the access path into the other is efficient (i.e. it is indexed). An example here is where I have a table of "types" (e.g. a table of valid status codes) and another table that takes one of those types as values for one of its columns. To flesh this out a little bit, consider the following:

```
create table dbo.OrderStatusCode (
   OrderStatusCodeID tinyint not null,
      constraint [PK_OrderStatusCode] primary key clustered (OrderStatusCodeID),
   Name varchar(255) not null
);

insert into dbo.OrderStatusCode (OrderStatusCodeID, Name)
values 
    (1, 'New'),
    (2, 'Open'),
    (3, 'In Process'),
    (4, 'Shipped'),
    (5, 'Closed'),
    (6, 'Returned');

create table dbo.Orders (
   OrderID int identity not null,
      constraint [PK_Orders] primary key clustered (OrderID),
   OrderStatusCodeID tinyint not null,
      constraint [FK_Orders_OrderStatusCode] foreign key
      (OrderStatusCodeID) references dbo.OrderStatusCode(OrderStatusCodeID)
   --«other stuff for the order table»
);

create index [IX_Orders__OrderStatusCodeID] on dbo.Orders (OrderStatusCodeID);

select o.*
from dbo.Orders as o
join dbo.OrderStatusCode as osc
    on o.OrderStatusCodeID = osc.OrderStatusCodeID
where osc.Name in ('New', 'Open', 'In Process');
```

Presumably, the number of Order records vastly outnumbers the number of OrderStatusCode records. Also, because of the non-clustered index on Orders.OrderStatusCode, access by that column is efficient in that table. So, nested loops can be used here to do the following (in pseudo-code):

- For each of the status codes ("New", "Open", "In Process")

  - Get the OrderStatusCodeID associated with that status code
  - Use the [IX_Orders__OrderStatusCodeID] index on orders to look up rows that have that OrderStatusCodeID

By contrast, a hash match is somewhat a method of last resort as it's the most expensive of the three join algorithms (generally speaking). That is, you don't have the conditions for either the nested loops or merge join algorithms. This is seen in cases like:
   - Neither side of the join is small
   - One or both sides of the join are inefficient in terms of how easy it is to find rows that match the join predicates

Note, that in all cases, these decisions are made by the optimizer based on statistics. If your statistics don't accurately reflect the underlying data, the optimizer can make a bad choice and pick an inappropriate join algorithm for your data. "Trust, but verify"!

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of articles about how the optimizer chooses join types such as [this one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2115/understanding-sql-server-physical-joins/).  Some of the real granular specifics may vary depending on which version of SQL Server you're talking aboug.

Comment: Not really an answer.

Comment: I linked an article that explains the kinds of scenarios when the different join types are used.  That would exactly the answer the question that was asked.  I'm not going to be a jerk and say "try Google" but I am also not going to give a long explanation when it's covered in many articles, including the one I linked.

Comment: At the risk of being hypocritical, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers provide some context as to why I didn't consider this a good answer.

Comment: You're doing more than risking being hypocritical.  Notice that nobody else has helped this guy at all ... because what he's asking can be found in a bunch of articles and he really should have just done a quick Google search.  My most sincere apologies for breaking your sacred rules and helping him out where nobody else has.  That being said, why don't you go ahead and formulate a great and appropriate response for him instead of spending your time being unproductive?

Comment: Okay… relax. If you'd like, I can give you back your fake internet points and you can continue being oblivious on how things are done here. And notice that my links weren't presented as answers to a question; they were comments. To be explicit, an answer should *stand on its own*. Sometimes, you can link to supporting content (and you should!), but if that link dies, the answer should still be valuable for anyone who comes to this site in the future asking the same question.

Comment: And you still haven't added anything meaningful to the conversation.  You still haven't done anything to answer the guy's question.  And again, whether or not that link persists, the same basic truth remains: the answer being sought is readily available in 5 seconds via any number of Google searches and that won't change.  Again, really, thank you for contributing.  You are making the world a better place.